# RedHat/CentOS 7.1: Change names of Gnome workspaces

Tags: rhel, gnome, workspaces

RedHat/CentOS 7.1.1503; GNOME Shell 3.8.4

I name my workspaces after current projects I'm working on (for 1-4 weeks). How can I rename them from "1" "2"... to something like "Vienna" "Berlin"?

In CentOS6 I just right clicked on the workspace panel add-on and renamed them in the properties.

I already found the "Workspace Lables" extension ( https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/551/workspace-labels/ ) but this does not allow me to change the names.

Answer (score 5):

OK, found a way via gsettings:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences workspace-names "['Com', 'Vienna', 'Test1', 'Test2','Test3']"
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences num-workspaces "5"
```

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add one thing to the Nico's answer.

When you run this command, if you get the `GLib-GIO-Message`:

```
 GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.
```

check the path to the command. In my case running `which gsettings` showed path to the anacoda folder:

```
 .../anaconda3/bin/gsettings
```

Using absolute path to the system `gsettings` solved the problem:

```
 /usr/bin/gsettings set ...
```

PS. This answer is based on one answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/916334/ubuntu-16-04-glib-gio-message-using-the-memory-gsettings-backend-your-settin)

Answer (score 2):

[Workspace Indicator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/21/workspace-indicator/) is a part of the core extensions and allows naming workspaces.

Once installed, go into the extension settings and then double click on the workspace you want to rename.

Comment: The question asks how to do it... perhaps you could elaborate with instructions?

Answer (score 0):

use apps->utilities->tweak->extensions->workspace indicator->settings(gear icon) to rename

Of course you have to install the extensions first....

BTW if anyone known how to make a shortcut for this, I'd appreciate it. One of the things I really miss from Centos 6 is the ability to right-click on the workspace name and rename it.